# C# WPF application permissions questions

Tags: c#, wpf, permissions, wmi, etw

I'm writing a C# WPF application that:

1. Collects hardware information through WMI (with `ManagementObjectSearcher`)
2. Captures processes' ETW draw events to measure FPS (with `TraceEventSession`)

I use *Setup Project*'s installer to distribute the app.
But, after installing on another computer, exe only opens with admin rights.

Google didn't help me to find the answer to:

1. Why does my app runs without permission on my PC?
2. Which task requires permissions and how should I know about it?
3. Is there a way to solve the problem without permission?
4. Why doesn't my app ask for permissions as other apps do?

I would greatly appreciate an answer to one or all of these questions! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Many operations that involve the WMI management interfaces require admin rights, that's just a fact. You didn't exactly specify what you do there, but querying some hardware information is likely to require this.

To test what call exactly requires admin rights, run the app on your computer without admin rights and check which call fails. You can even debug your app in that mode (just make sure you *don't* start Visual Studio as admin).

To make your app require admin rights, create an application manifest file (Use the "Application Manifest" template in the "new file" window) and add a line `requestedExecutionLevel` below the `<requestedPrivileges>` node as follows:

```
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
```

This will result in Windows asking for admin rights each time the App is started. This is a global setting for the whole application. It is not possible to ask for the permission only if you need it.

Comment: I collect os version, cpu, gpu, motherboard and ram info.

Comment: @gavrilikhin.d As said, you have to check each call separately. If you implemented error handling correctly, you should see which call fails when running as non-admin.

Comment: Ok, now I want to trigger UAC only once (at installation). Is it possible? I heard that rewriting my app as Windows Service might help

Comment: Yes, services may start with admin permissions. Another (probably easier) alternative is to start the application trough the task scheduler. That can also work around the UAC prompt.